# Try to convert file into excel...[macro]

Tags: python, vba

The txt file is converting to the Excel xls file by using Python. But some of the new line will not function when the text file is converted to the Excel xls file.

```
 eg: In the txt file, the data is as follow:

           1.ABC
           2.DEF
           3.GHI

     When it is converted to excel xls, the data is showed as follow:

           1.ABC 2.DEF 3.GHI
```

The newline is not available. I wish to initiate the newline with using macros.

Comment: How are we supposed to point out what's wrong with your code if you don't show us the code?

Comment: i m sorry that i m not able to show the code. I hope to do this with the macro since the result is in excel file.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is first read the  text file and store each line as list element. Then using pandas to_excel you can easily write that list in an excel file. 
Pandas .to_excel works with pandas to datframe, so we need to convert our list to pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
#Let's say you have text file as my_text.txt
text_file = open("my_text.txt", "r")

#store each line as list element of list lines
lines = text_file.readlines()

#Convert list to pandas dataframe and store it in df
df = pd.DataFrame(lines)
df.to_excel('output.xlsx', header=False, index=False)
```

You will get output.xlsx file with your desired result.